# How do I get a list of uploaded videos for a certain channel?

Tags: youtube-api, channel, youtube-channels

I am trying to get a list of video ids for all uploaded videos to a channel.

my api call is something like 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=relevance&part=guidespark&q=engage&channelId=UCU_EHiwIzRLm6RbNNzeZijQ&maxResults=25&key={API_KEY}

It is showing the error like

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.part",
    "reason": "unknownPart",
    "message": "guidespark",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "guidespark"
 }
}
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set part=snippet in url part
hope this helps.
use all required fields

Answer (score 3):

The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more search resource properties that the API response will include. The part names that you can include in the parameter value are id and snippet. If the parameter identifies a property that contains child properties, the child properties will be included in the response. For example, in a search result, the snippet property contains other properties that identify the result's title, description, and so forth. If you set part=snippet, the API response will also contain all of those nested properties